# The number of hyperplanes  determining the integer points of a polyhedron

Tags: convex-geometry, co.combinatorics, integer-programming

This question is inspired by [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/47345/when-is-a-local-artin-c-algebra-a-subring-of-ct-tn).

Let $P \subset \mathbb R_{+}^n$ be a convex polyhedron whose complement in $\mathbb R_{+}^n$ has finite volume. Let $Int(P) = P \cap \mathbb N^n$. (For motivation: they are the set of exponent vectors of  integrally closed, $0$-dimensional monomial  ideals in $\mathbb C[x_1,\cdots, x_n]$, but we probably don't need it here).

> **Question 1**: Is there a nice characterization (perhaps using the corner points) of when we can find *one* hyperplane $H$ that separate $Int(P)$ and its complement in $\mathbb N^n$?   Namely, such that $Int(P)$ is precisely the intersection of a closed half-space defined by $H$ and $\mathbb N^n$?
>
> **Question 2**: More generally, we can look at the least number of hyperplanes needed to cut out $Int(P)$. Is such number studied in the literature? Any good algorithm to find it?

Some examples: for $n=2$, let $P$ be the convex hull of $\{(0,2); (1,1); (3,0)\}$. Then one can find $H : 2x+3y=5$.  But for the convex hull of $\{(0,3); (1,1); (3,0)\}$, it is easy to see that one needs $2$ lines.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to both your questions is Gomory cuts. From a non-interger extreme point $x$ of $P$ it is easy to find an hyperplane $H$ which separate $x$ from $Int(P)$. Such an hyperplane is called a Gomory cut. It can be shown that by applying this procedure a finite number of time one can describe $Int(P)$ as a finite intersection of halfspaces.

I don't have the exact references around but it seems that this document contains all the details: http://www2.math.uni-paderborn.de/fileadmin/Mathematik/AG-Eisenbrand/publications/diss.pdf

Comment: See also the Wikipedia description of Gomory cuts:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutting-plane_method#Gomory.27s_cut